# Listando todos os arquivos da minha aplicação

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu quero fazer um backup da minha aplicação e enviar pro meu bucket no S3. Mas pra isso, eu preciso primeiro listar os diretórios (junto com os arquivos), pra depois fazer o upload pro S3.

Eu [encontrei esse tutorial](http://blog.katworksgames.com/2014/01/26/nodejs-deploying-files-to-aws-s3/) mas ele não me serve, porque é preciso colocar cada caminho pra listar os arquivos, o que torna o código desnecessariamente maior do que deve ser.

OBS: A minha aplicação é feita em Node, junto com o Express e Angular.

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz? :D

Comment: Você quer listar arquivos incluindo subpastas? Qual sistema operacional?

Comment: eu consegui fazer @Caffé, listei eles e agora estou tentando armazer o código desses files em uma váriavel. Você saberia como fazer isso?

Comment: Possivelmente sim. Atualize sua pergunta ou exclua e crie uma nova se a necessidade mudou completamente.

Comment: @MarceloAlves poste ali a sua solução para que outras pessoas possam ver quando elas tiverem a mesma dúvida que vc teve.
Depois cria uma nova pergunta com essa nova demanda que vc teve pro pessoal poder te ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui fica uma funcão que usamos no site novo do MooTools.

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
function getFiles(dir, files_, fileType){

    var regex = fileType ? new RegExp('\\' + fileType + '$') : '';

    return fs.readdirSync(dir).reduce(function(allFiles, file){
        var name = path.join(dir, file);
        if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()){
            getFiles(name, allFiles, fileType);
        } else if (file.match(regex)){
            allFiles.push(name);
        }
        return allFiles;
    }, files_ || []);

}
```

A função é sincrona e aceita **3 argumentos**:

- a diretoria
- uma array de ficheiros já em memória (este argumento é também usado pela função quando se chama a sí prória)
- o tipo de ficheiro/extensão

Ela retorna uma array com todos os ficheiros dentro da directoria e sub-diretorias.